# Pathauto: How to allow duplicate url

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I am just wondering. Is it possible to allow duplicate urls with pathauto. In some projects the "duplicate content penalty" does not matter: Internal projects, shops (products)...

Anyway, how do I configure pathauto to allow such duplicate/generate them:

I have an article with two taxonomy terms apple+pear

```
[node:field_category]/[node:title]
```

results in

```
apple-pear/node-title
```

what I looking for is:

```
apple/node-title
pear/node-title
```

Comment: You can [do it with rules apparently](https://drupal.org/node/457842)

Comment: @Clive I thought about rules too, but since I am not very experienced with rules it might get complicated...

Comment: If I understand that thread properly, rules is the only way to do it short of coding your own solution

Comment: With Redirect you can create a new URL but with 301 redirect. So what you do is as soon as node is saved, create the same node with another url.